# Query data in time interval that spans two days in mysql

Tags: mysql

I need to count data for a given <week | month | custom> interval grouped by a given time schedule that possibly spans 2 days. The chunks depends on customers working schedules.

Possible cases (for one month interval) :

- all data from June 01, 2022 to July 01, 2022, each day between 08:00 pm and 04:00 am (overnight)
- all data from June 01, 2022 to June 30, 2022, each day between 04:00 am and 08:00 pm
- all data from June 01, 2022 to June 30, 2022, each day between 00:00 am and 23:59 pm

Here's what I came up with:

```
WITH RECURSIVE seq AS (
    SELECT
        0 AS value
    UNION ALL
    SELECT
        value + 1
    FROM
        seq
    WHERE
        value < 29
),
period AS (
    SELECT
        '2022-06-01 20:00' + INTERVAL (value * 24 * 60) MINUTE AS start,
        '2022-06-01 20:00' + INTERVAL (value * 24 * 60) MINUTE + INTERVAL (8* 60) MINUTE AS end
    FROM seq
    ORDER BY value DESC
)
SELECT *
FROM (
    SELECT
    DATE(sd.timestamp - INTERVAL(LEAST(20, 4)) HOUR) as date,  
    SUM(...) as count,
FROM sensor_data sd
        WHERE sd.timestamp BETWEEN '2022-06-01 20:00' AND '2022-07-01 04:00'
            AND HOUR(sd.timestamp) >= 20 AND HOUR(sd.timestamp) < 4
GROUP BY 
    date
) main_data
INNER JOIN period ON DATE(period.start) = date
```

Unfortunately in doesn't work for the first case (spans two days). Any ideas?

Comment: What is precise MySQL version? the output for `SELECT VERSION();`.

Comment: mysql version 8

Comment: If so then simply generate base calendar table which contains start and end datetime value for each day with needed time interval (use recursive CTE), and join your data table to it by the condition that the table value is between calendar row start-end values. In this case the criteria data as start-length (start at 08:00 pm, length 8 hours) is more useful.

Comment: I updated the query, this what I did originally. But it doesn't work for schedules between two days.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```sql
WITH RECURSIVE
cte AS (
    SELECT datetime_from range_from, 
           datetime_from + INTERVAL range_length HOUR range_till
    UNION ALL
    SELECT range_from + INTERVAL 1 DAY,
           range_till + INTERVAL 1 DAY
    FROM cte
    WHERE range_till < datetime_till
)
SELECT range_from, range_till, COUNT(*) rows_amount
FROM cte
LEFT JOIN test ON test.dt BETWEEN range_from AND range_till
GROUP BY 1, 2;
```

[DEMO](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=b7d5d6b34df04f23f1cdfd2cd8645211) with some explanations.